# A reduction of an ester with DIBAL-H to alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry

I will do a reduction with DIBAL-H and after I need to do the workup of this reaction. I have to quench the reaction with MeOH at 0°C.And I will let the reaction return to rt. As shown below :
[image]

I'll then add satured NaCl and Et2O and I'll then filter that in celite.

The thing is that I don't understand why I should filter in celite and what is the goal of that. Is it to remove subproducts ?

Here is the link to the work that I am trying to reproduce : Gropp, C.; Fischer, S.; Husch, T.; Trapp, N.; Carreira, E. M.; Diederich, F. Molecular Recognition and Cocrystallization of Methylated and Halogenated Fragments of Danicalipin A by Enantiopure Alleno-Acetylenic Cage Receptors. J. Am. Chem. Soc. 2020, 142 (10), 4749–4755. https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.9b13217.

Thank you in advance for your indication

Answer (score 4):

Aqueous work up of aluminium-based reducing agents results in the formation of aluminium hydroxide residues which form fine suspensions/gels. These do not separate easily from your organic phase unless you take measures to remove them. Celite filtration should give you a clear two phase system that you can separate.